# Fetch previous and next row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to fetch all the current rows, along with the previous and next rows, in a separate row.

For example:

**Table1** has 6 rows:

```
Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4
----------------------------------
1        abc      1        21
2        def      2        14
3        ghi      2        25
4        jkl      1        34
5        mno      2        23
6        pqr      1        54
7        stu      1        64
8        vw       2        67
9        xyz      2        43
10       yre      1        16
11       tuy      2        53
12       mou      1        30
```

Table ordered by `Column4`:

[image]

Select *previous* and *next* rows from the above table `Where Column3 = 1` and then `Order By Column4 Desc`.

And I have the `Column4 = 21`, based on this condition I need to select only the Previous and next records.

Expected result:

```
Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4
----------------------------------
12       mou      1        30
 1       abc      1        21
10       yre      1        16
```

Comment: `WHERE Column3 = 1` will give you the results you want; I don't see the problem here. What are you actually asking, and what about the statement the `WHERE` you provided doesn't work?

Comment: 'Previous' and 'next' have no meaning without order, how do you know which is the 'next' record?

Comment: This is sample code, Actually, My problem is not with the where condition, it is how will u fetch previous and next record.

Comment: Just use the `WHERE` you gave your question: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bb0edc5d96a49615459ded00b5f92419)

Comment: Define "previous" and "next" then. Tables are sets of rows, they have no ordering unless you give them one. For example, ordering them by `Column1` would make sense, but then it's not clear if you want additional rows to also have `Column3 = 1` or not. What is the *actual result set* you want, including *all* rows?

Comment: Who closed this question? It is perfectly clear to me. I was just about to post my response!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [Column1] INT
   ,[Column2] CHAR(3)
   ,[Column3] INT
   ,[Column4] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4])
VALUES (1, 'abc', 1, 21)
      ,(2, 'def', 2, 14)
      ,(3, 'ghi', 2, 25)
      ,(4, 'jkl', 1, 34)
      ,(5, 'mno', 2, 23)
      ,(6, 'pqr', 1, 54)
      ,(7, 'stu', 1, 64)
      ,(8, 'vw', 2, 67)
      ,(9, 'xyz', 2, 43)
      ,(10, 'yre', 1, 16)
      ,(11, 'tuy', 2, 53)
      ,(12, 'mou', 1, 30);

WITH DataSource As
(
    SELECT *
         ,LAG([Column4]) OVER (ORDER BY [Column4] DESC) AS [Next]
         ,LEAD([Column4]) OVER (ORDER BY [Column4] DESC) AS [Prev]
    FROM @DataSource
    WHERE [Column3] = 1
)
SELECT [Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4]
FROM DataSource
WHERE [Column4] = 21
    OR [Next] = 21
    OR [Prev] = 21
ORDER BY [Column4] DESC;
```

[image]